# Event handler in javafx for removing listbox selection

Tags: javafx

I am trying to create an event handler to remove a selected item from the listbox. So basically I make my selections from the combobox and those selections are added to the list box. If I click on an item in the listbox is is supposed to be removed. I am not doing so good with this can someone please give me a hand. I do have some code commented out because that is something else I tried. Thank you.

```
    ComboBox<String> beverageComboBox = new ComboBox<String>();
    ObservableList<String> items1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList(beverages);
    beverageComboBox.getItems().addAll(items1);

    Label bo = new Label("Beverage Ordered");
    pane.add(bo, 2, 5);

    ListView<String> list1 = new ListView<>();

    beverageComboBox.setOnAction((e) -> {
        list1.getItems().add(beverageComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
    });

    list1.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> {
        list1.getItems().remove(items1); 
    });

//  list1.setOnMouseClicked( e -> {
    //  list1.getItems().remove(items1); 
//  });

    pane.add(list1, 3, 5);
    GridPane.setRowSpan(list1, 5);
```

Comment: Are you stuck with the item removal from listView on its selection ?

Comment: You work with observable lists, why don't you try to bind them? It would maybe solve your problem automatically.
ComboBox.itemsProperty.bind(items1); or similar

Comment: Yes @ItachiUchiha I would like to select the item from the listbox and click on it and have it removed